# Blur/Focus event not allowing click on label to bubble and set focus to the appropriate field

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling

I'm using the following code to add a class on focus and remove it on blur of any input field. This class is responsible for showing or hiding some helper text below the field.  The issue I have is that when I leave the field and click on label of a radio button, it removes the class of the field I blurred from correctly but it does not check the radio item I have clicked on. In other words I have to click it twice to get the radio button to be selected. I have created a Fiddle to illustrate. If you mouse into the first field you get the helper text, if you then click on the last input it correctly hides the helper text on the first input and sets focus to the last input. If you mouse into the first field and then try clicking a radio button, it correctly hides the helper text but does not select the radio button. https://jsfiddle.net/mn5pyqd1/12/

```
$('input').bind('blur', function () {
    $(this).parent('div[class^="input-wrap"]').removeClass('fusion-helper');
}).bind('focus', function () {
    $(this).parent('div[class^="input-wrap"]').addClass('fusion-helper');
});
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML or even better, a JSFiddle example? I don't think the code in your question will be the problem

Comment: I've added a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mn5pyqd1/12/

Comment: The problem appears to be the shifting alignment. When you hide the helper text, everything moves up and your click misses the radio. I'd find a better way to show the helper text or at least, add a delay to removing the class.